# Master/detail flow or navigation drawer ? which is better for display detail data about list items?

Tags: android, design-patterns, user-experience, android-navigation

I have a list of persons that when user click on one item the app show its detail ! i used **dual pane Master/detail design pattern** for tablet size and for small size it just replace list with detail fragment.
The problem is that my manager think its better to change this design with **navigation drawer** ! what is the best choice for this case ? **navigation drawer** or **master/detail** design ?
which is better for user experience ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) is:

> a panel that transitions in from the left edge of the screen and displays the app’s main navigation options.

Per the [App Structure guide](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html):

> A navigation drawer is a slide-out menu that allows users to **switch between views of your app**. It can hold a large number of items and is accessible from anywhere in your app. Navigation drawers show your app's top-level views, but can also provide navigation to lower-level screens. This makes them particularly suitable for complex apps.

And the [Material Design structure guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-side-nav) state:

> The content in the left nav is ideally navigation- or identity-based.

The Navigation Drawer is **not** listed as a mechanism for [multi-pane layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html), while a master/detail multi-pane layout is specifically mentioned.

In short: Navigation Drawer is for navigation only and **not** for displaying a master list with corresponding detail.

In fact, one of the framework engineers wrote [a Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/8j2GVw72i1E) back in 2013 specifically about how they tried to use `DrawerLayout` (the class name for the navigation drawer) for displaying master/detail style content and instead built a separate component, [SlidingPaneLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) specifically to address this issue of displaying master/detail on smaller screens without using the Navigation Drawer affordances or pattern as they just did not fit. Note that this has fallen slightly out of favor in Material design, with a re-emphasis on a traditional master/detail pattern with [meaningful transition animations](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html).

Comment: if i understand correctly its better to use master/detail in my app , but in smaller screen size drawer make good `UX `for choose different master item ! or im thinking wrong ?

Comment: Read the Google+ post I linked: the framework engineers specifically looked at that case and found that **no**, the navigation drawer was absolutely not the right pattern. So much so that they added a new component to handle that exact case.

Comment: I'm finding the master/detail unsatisfactory for the different views. Drawer is far superior on small screens, but master/detail works well on large screens.
There should be a template that sets you of for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 demo apps to see the difference on a phone.

1. Master Detail flow:

The master page (menu, or list page) will always be displayed to the user first and the master page covers the **whole** screen. If the user does not tap, he/she will not notice there is a detailed page.

2. Navigation drawer:

The detailed page will be displayed to the user first, with a navigation menu (3 stripes menu) on the top left corner.
If the user taps the navigation menu, he/she will see a sliding out page, which covers only half of the screen. For the most of the time, the menu screen will be hidden.

So they are actually very different from the design aspect. Of course, they have similarities during implementation.